# What is difference between the roles of Manu and Prajapati?

Tags: brahma, creation, manu

It is said that Vishnu created Brahma, Brahma opened the Golden Egg and created the Universe and the Heaven. He also created the 4 children from his brain or head. He then created 9 Prajapatis and 14 Manus. If that's the case what is the difference between the roles of Prajapatis and Manus?

Also, can we say that the 4 children from the brain or head of Brahma are the 4 Vedas and the 9 Prajapatis are the 9 planets? If that's the case, what about the rest of the Universe? Are there other Prajapatis for other parts of the Universe?

Comment: No, the Prajapatis have no connections to the planets, and they're usually not numbered at nine anyway.  The Prajapatis are charged with producing offspring in order to populate the Universe. It's true that Swayambhuva Manu is the progenitor of mankind, but that's not the general purpose of Manus.  (Pretty much Vaivasvata Manu's only descendants are the members of the solar and lunar dynasties, so most of the rest of the humans in the world aren't descended from him.) Their general purpose is to rule the human race and to provide humanity with laws.

Comment: Wow. So Manu provided laws and Prajapatis produced offsprings? This is different from what I have read so far on this forum.. I always thought it was Manu who is the progenitor of mankind.. So are you saying some offsprings come from Manu and others from Prajapatis?

Comment: Well, Swayambhuva Manu genuinely is the progenitor of mankind, but that doesn't mean the rest of the Manus are. As far as the Prajapatis go, when I say they produce offspring I don't just mean human offspring; Marichi's son Kashyapa, for instance, is the father of the Adityas and Daityas.